# Command-Line PHP: problems in mixing fread(STDIN,...) and fgets(STDIN)

Tags: php, stream, command-line-interface, stdin

I am working on a command-line-script witch uses fread (for yes/no,...) and fgets (for manually validating values,...).

The problem is if I enter more than ... chars (\n is a char, too), this chars are already inputed in the next fgets/fread-function.

I tried fflush(STDIN), but it didn't work. I also tried stream_get_line(STDIN,1024); which was recommended by someone in a simmelar question, but then I have to input nearly unendless much chars until the programm continues (I quit).

How to get PHP to delete keyboard-buffer before using fgets/fread?

Comment: Could you show us a relevant sample of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is compiled with the **Readline** module (it's quite common) you may just use `readline()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

```
$input = readline( 'Prompt: ' );
```

`readline()` simplifies the process of reading input from the terminal.

Comment: I get PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function readline() in ... on line ...
I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57)

Comment: I used the Mac OS X Mavericks default PHP which is 5.4.40. You need to have the **Readline** module in your PHP setup (but it's pretty common). See the requirements here: http://php.net/manual/en/readline.setup.php (I edit my answer for completeness)